# Where am I losing my object context?

Tags: php

One more try at this.  I've already had my previous question down voted.

I am loading a class through a class that is never instantiated via a static method.  The class I am loading however is supposed to be instantiated but I suspect that execution never gets that far.  There is nothing static in this class, but php keeps throwing:

```
**Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context**
```

Here is the class in it's entirety:

```
class Config{


    public $_config;



    public function load()
    {
        $modules = array();
        $modules = scandir(MOD);
        $n = count($modules);
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        {
            if($modules[$i]==='.'||$modules[$i]==='..'||strpos($modules[$i],'.'))
            { unset($modules[$i]); }

        }
        $modules = array_values($modules);
        $m = count($modules);

        for($i=0;$i<$m;$i++)
        {
            $mod = $modules[$i];
            $this->_config[$mod] = array();// **Error thrown here.**
            $cfgfiles = scandir(MOD.DS.$mod.DS.'config');
            $num = count($cfgfiles);

            for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
            {
                if($cfgfiles[$i]==='.'||$cfgfiles[$i]==='..')
                    { unset($cfgfiles[$i]); }
            }

            $cfgfiles = array_values($cfgfiles);
            $k = count($cfgfiles);

            for($j=0;$j<$k;$j++)
            {
                include(MOD.DS.$mod.DS.'config'.DS.$cfgfiles[$j]);
                $modcfg = substr($cfgfiles[$j], 0, -4);
                $this->_config[$mod][$modcfg] = array();
                $this->_config[$mod][$modcfg] = $cfg;
            }

        } 
        return $this->_config;
    }

}
```

More information outlining my problem can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653956/using-this-when-not-in-object-context-but-supposedly-i-am

Ok, as requested, here is the code that calls this class and yes, it is a static function.  This is what I was wondering about, but the fact that the function in the other class was static did not seem to have any effect on the loading of other classes, only this one.

```
public static function init()
{
    $farray = scandir(SYS);

    for ($i=0;$i<count($farray);$i++)
        { if(strpos($farray[$i],'.php'))
        {
        $item = $farray[$i];
        require (SYS.DS.$item);
        $className = substr($item, 0, -4);
        self::$_names[] = $className;
        $obj = new $className();
        self::$_objs[] = $obj;
        self::$_classes = array_combine(self::$_names, self::$_objs);
        }
    }
}


public static function getClass($class)
{
    if(isset(self::$_classes[$class]))
        { return self::$_classes[$class]; }
    else
        { return false; }
}
```

Ok, I added a `debug_backtrace()` at the line just before the `error($this->_config[$mod]=array())` and this is what I get, but I do not understand what it means.

```
array(2) 
 { [0]=> array(6) 
{ ["file"]=> string(25) "C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\fw.php" 
["line"]=> int(45) 
["function"]=> string(4) "load" 
["class"]=> string(6) "Config" 
["type"]=> string(2) "::" 
["args"]=> array(0) { } } 

[1]=> array(6) 
{ ["file"]=> string(26) "C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php" 
["line"]=> int(31) 
["function"]=> string(4) "init" 
["class"]=> string(2) "Fw" 
["type"]=> string(2) "::" 
["args"]=> array(0) { } } }
```

---

Ok, I've done everyone who responded to this question a dis-service. It turns out that I was indeed inadvertently making a static method call to Config::load in Fw::init.  Because I had made so many revisions and worked on it until I was bleary eyed I unknowingly ended up with two different version of the same class, one on my server and one in my editor.

I am now going off to learn how to use a source control application.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? And where is the code that is instantiating this class?

Comment: Aside: I'd swap `scandir()` for `glob()`

Comment: I'd want to see how you're loading this class. And also how you are calling it.

Comment: Something like `Config::load()` would trigger that error.

Comment: @Matthew calling `Config::load()` would cause another error - `load()` isn't `static`.

Comment: @Mike Brant:  The link above that says Using $this when not in object context but supposedly I am will take to you to the function that calls this class.  I didn't put any more details here in order to avoid cluttering up stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarkJackson I think in this case it would be extremely useful to find out how the class is being instantiated and worked with and to understand exactly which line of code is causing the fatal error.

Comment: Have you tried loading the class manually and trying to emulate the code your factory is doing? I'd imagine you'll find your doing a static request somewhere in your calling code.

Comment: Mark try a couple things: A) add a die statement after the $this->_ call, if it gets there then its another iteration thats causing the issue B) if A doesn't help (ie it doesn't die()) then add a backtrace before the $this-> - http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php and see how the php script got there and if that fails C) get a profiler and step through the code!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using $this when not in object context but supposedly I am](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653956/using-this-when-not-in-object-context-but-supposedly-i-am)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely thing going on here is that you're calling the `Config::load()` method statically. This type of code will result in the error you quoted in your question:

```
Config::load()
```

You can fix it by instantiating an object and calling the `load()` method on the instance. Like this:

```
$config = new Config();
$config->load();
```

Comment: Actually I'm calling:$className = substr($item, 0, -4);
            self::$_names[] = $className;
            $obj = new $className();
            self::$_objs[] = $obj;
            self::$_classes = array_combine(self::$_names, self::$_objs);    But that is in another class.

Comment: @MarkJackson Were in that code does the `load()` method get called?

Comment: @Asaph Check the link to his other question, the factory method is there.

Comment: @Asaph: it doesn't get called in that code segment.  The load method gets called on the index page.  The index page calls Fw::init and that loads and instantiates classes in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try stating that $_config = array() to start with:

`public $_config = array();`

See if that helps.

It looks fine, I have spaced it out better for you...

```
class Config {

    public $_config = array();

    public function load()
    {
        $modules = array();
        $modules = scandir(MOD);
        $n = count($modules);
        for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
        {
            if($modules[$i]==='.' || $modules[$i]==='..' || strpos($modules[$i],'.'))
            { 
                unset($modules[$i]); 
            }
        }
        $modules = array_values($modules);
        $m = count($modules);

        for($i=0; $i < $m; $i++)
        {
            $mod = $modules[$i];
            $this->_config[$mod] = array();// **Error thrown here.**
            $cfgfiles = scandir(MOD.DS.$mod.DS.'config');
            $num = count($cfgfiles);

            for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++)
            {
                if($cfgfiles[$i]==='.' || $cfgfiles[$i]==='..')
                { 
                    unset($cfgfiles[$i]); 
                }
            }

            $cfgfiles = array_values($cfgfiles);
            $k = count($cfgfiles);

            for($j=0; $j < $k; $j++)
            {
                include(MOD.DS.$mod.DS.'config'.DS.$cfgfiles[$j]);
                $modcfg = substr($cfgfiles[$j], 0, -4);
                $this->_config[$mod][$modcfg] = array();
                $this->_config[$mod][$modcfg] = $cfg;
            }

        } 
        return $this->_config;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try making a temporary array and adding your data to that then finally before you return, setting _config to the array

Comment: Just seems like a waste of time @SHTester that should not make any difference what so ever.